# Error in using Karma with SystemJS, gulp, and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, systemjs, gulp-karma, karma-qunit

I am new to `node.js` stack like `npm`, `gulp` etc. I had wrote some JavaScript unit test cases earlier, and now want to use `Karma` as test runner. However, after a few attempts I am completely lost now.

To start, I have following project configurations:

- `SystemJS` as module loader.
- Folder structre (some are omitted for brevity):

  ```
  project
  |
  |--build //contains all gulp tasks
  |
  |--dist //contains the output (*.html, *.js etc.)
  |
  |--jspm_packages 
  |
  |--node_modules
  |
  |--src //contains the source .html, and *.ts
  |
  |--tests //contains unit tests in *.ts. I also have a gulp task to build tests/**/*.ts to *.js in the same folder.
  |
  |--typings //contains type definitions
  |
  |--config.js //contains SystemJS configuration
  |
  |--karma.conf.js
  ```
- `karma.conf.js`

  ```
  // Karma configuration        

  module.exports = function (config) {
      config.set({
          basePath: '',
          frameworks: [ 'qunit'],
          files: [
              'jspm_packages/system.js',
              //'config.js',
              'dist/custom/*.js' //,
              //'tests/**/*.js'
          ],
          exclude: [        ],
          preprocessors: {        },
          reporters: ['progress'],
          port: 9876,
          colors: true,
          logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
          autoWatch: true,
          browsers: ['Chrome'],
          singleRun: false,
          concurrency: Infinity
      });
  }
  ```

However, whenever I do `karma start`, I have error `Uncaught TypeError: Unexpected anonymous System.register call.`.  Is there anyway to resolve this?

**Other Attempts:**

1. Tried to create a gulp task, according to https://github.com/karma-runner/gulp-karma. But have same problem.
2. Tried to use [`karma-systemjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-systemjs). And the `karma.conf.js` was different as follows:

   ```
   // Karma configuration        

   module.exports = function (config) {
       config.set({
           ...
           frameworks: [ 'systemjs', 'qunit'],
           plugins: ['karma-systemjs', 'karma-chrome-launcher', 'karma-firefox-launcher'],
           systemjs: {
               configFile: 'config.js',
               serveFiles: ['jspm_packages/**/*.js'],
               config: {
                   transpiler: 'babel'
               }
           },
           ...
       });
   }
   ```

   And in this case I got following error, though I have both `SystemJs` and `Babel` installed:

   ```
   [WARNING] Looking up paths with require.resolve() is deprecated.
   Please add "systemjs" to your SystemJS config paths.
   Cannot find "systemjs".
     Did you forget to install it ?
     npm install systemjs --save-dev
   [WARNING] Looking up paths with require.resolve() is deprecated.
   Please add "babel" to your SystemJS config paths.
   Cannot find "babel-core".
     Did you forget to install it ?
     npm install babel-core --save-dev
   ```

Any help in this regard will be great.

Comment: Perhaps try adding `systemjs` to the `frameworks` property in your first Karma configuration file.  If that doesn't work, then add the `systemjs` property from your second karma conf file to the first one.  Exclude the `plugins` property for now.

Comment: @GenYDeveloper Thank You for your comment. this seems to work as it results in removal of the `SystemJS` error. Additionally asking, now Karma ignores the test cases completely and not running any of them. The message on console is `Executed 0 of 0 ERROR`. Any reason why?

Comment: Did you uncomment the test files array value on the `files` property?

Comment: Yes I have done so and currently testing for unit tests of only one module: `tests/custom/MyTargetModule.js`.

Comment: Unfortunately I have never run into this problem myself, and don't know a solution off the top of my head.  I am busy right now, but will try to look at it when I have time.

Comment: @GenYDeveloper That's ok. Thank you anyway for your help. :)